# How to Form Submission/Processing in PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have created a form in HTML and want to complete the full cycle of   submitting it and have created a PHP script. Form code in HTML is below:

```
<form action = "script.php" method = "get">
        <br>
        username
<input
       Type = "text"
       name = "username"


       />
       <br>
lastname
<input
         type = "text"
         name = "lastname"
         />

firstname
<input 
          type = "text"
          name = "firstname" />
 Submit         
 <input 
          type = "submit"
          name = "submit" />
          </form>
</body>  
</html>
```

And in the PHP file I created the following script is 
My Question is the when I upload my PHP form file after submitting the form,  nothing is displayed on the page.

```
       <?php
         ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 $_GET["username"]."&nbsp;".$_GET["lastname"]."&nbsp;" .$_GET["firstname"];."&nbsp";.$_GET["submit"];

        echo "thank-you for submitting this information on my website";

       ?>
```

Comment: Could you upload the html to a separate service such as https://jsfiddle.net? The code you pasted into the question is not properly formatted and I can't tell if that's the issue or not.

Comment: @LiamBolling added in jsfiddle.net but have never used it I am not sure how to share it with you.

Comment: @JA21 is this your full code ??

Comment: @cody yes it complete HTML and PHP which is doing the receiving of the form.

Comment: @JA21 try this https://jsfiddle.net/9am5fnnL/ run this code

Answer (score 0):

Try this script.php

```
echo $_GET['username']." ".$_GET['lastname']." " .$_GET['firstname']." ".$_GET['submit'];
echo "thank-you for submitting this information on my website";
```

The script must begin with <\?php, without the backslash (\)

Comment: @cody and Igot Greg:  have got it to work atleast it is displaying some error messages. But now the error I am getting is Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\Apache24\htdocs\script.php on line 23

Comment: @JA21 You may add value="Submit" , together with type and name, for submit input, in the html form. So submit button will have a value to send to php.

Comment: @Igot Geg: I tried that but still the error is showing as in :Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\Apache24\htdocs\script.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: lastname in C:\Apache24\htdocs\script.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\Apache24\htdocs\script.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\Apache24\htdocs\script.php on line 23

Comment: @JA21 A notice is not an error. It just says that the fields of the form, were empty when submitted. You may learn more about 'Get' request at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    if(isset($_GET['submit']))
    {

        echo  $_GET["username"]."&nbsp;".$_GET["lastname"]."&nbsp;" .$_GET["firstname"];."&nbsp";.$_GET["submit"];


                    echo "thank-you for submitting this information on my website";
    }

     ?>
```